# How to create span tree in distributed tracing system using Golang

Tags: go, microservices, jaeger, opentracing

I already have a microservice and I want to apply distributed tracing for it.
I have written the following code to create a tracing span using jaeger and opentracing , but my problem is that it does not create parrent id and I am not able to see the span graph. It seems it only shows the default operations in UI dashboard.
I used docker-compose for config jaeger.

```
 jaeger:
  container_name: jaeger
  image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.39
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 5775:5775/udp
    - 6831:6831/udp
    - 6832:6832/udp
    - 5778:5778
    - 16686:16686
    - 14268:14268
    - 9411:9411
    
  environment:
    - COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true
    - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:16686"
    - COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT=9411
    - JAEGER_SERVICE_NAME=baran-endpoint
    - JAEGER_AGENT_HOST=jaeger
    - JAEGER_REPORTER_LOG_SPANS=true
    - JAEGER_SAMPLER_TYPE=const
    - JAEGER_SAMPLER_PARAM=1
    - JAEGER_SAMPLER_SERVER_URL=
  networks:
    - network-jaeger
```

I tried to implement a basic architecture in jaeger component,but it seems that i'm missing somthing in between.
[image]

```
var (
  TracingAnalysisEndpoint      = "http://localhost:26855/SaleService.svc"
)
const AgentSwitch = false

func NewJaegerTracer(service string) opentracing.Tracer {
    if AgentSwitch == true {
        return NewJaegerTracerAgent(service)
    }
    return NewJaegerTracerDirect(service)
}

func NewJaegerTracerDirect(service string) opentracing.Tracer {
    sender := transport.NewHTTPTransport(
        TracingAnalysisEndpoint,
    )
    tracer, _ := jaeger.NewTracer(service,
        jaeger.NewConstSampler(true),
        jaeger.NewRemoteReporter(sender, jaeger.ReporterOptions.Logger(jaeger.StdLogger)),
    )
    return tracer
}

func NewJaegerTracerAgent(service string) opentracing.Tracer {
    sender, _ := jaeger.NewUDPTransport("",0)
    tracer, _ := jaeger.NewTracer(service,
        jaeger.NewConstSampler(true),
        jaeger.NewRemoteReporter(sender, jaeger.ReporterOptions.Logger(jaeger.StdLogger)),
    )
    return tracer
}

func StartSpanFromRequest(tracer opentracing.Tracer, r *http.Request, funcDesc string) opentracing.Span {
 spanCtx, _ := Extract(tracer, r)
 return tracer.StartSpan(funcDesc, ext.RPCServerOption(spanCtx))
}

func Inject(span opentracing.Span, request *http.Request) error {
 return span.Tracer().Inject(
  span.Context(),
  opentracing.HTTPHeaders,
  opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(request.Header))
}

func Extract(tracer opentracing.Tracer, r *http.Request) (opentracing.SpanContext, error) {
 return tracer.Extract(
  opentracing.HTTPHeaders,
  opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(r.Header))
}
```

I created first span on one of my services.

```
  span:= config.StartSpanFromRequest(config.Tracer,ctx.Request(), "customer method")
  defer span.Finish()   
  span.LogKV(fmt.Sprintf("Customer not found: %s", request.Mobile))
```

It only shows the default operations in UI dashboard.
[image]

I can not create parent and child spans in my trace correctly.

[image]

I want to create spans in hierarchical order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a parent-child relationship between spans, you need to make sure the context of the parent span is passed to the child span creation process. That is often done by [propagating the span context through the headers](https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go#serializing-to-the-wire) in the case of HTTP requests.

So, modify your `StartSpanFromRequest`, making sure the function correctly [extracts](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-go/blob/8d8e8fcfd04de42b8482476abac6a902fca47c18/tracer.go#L354) the parent span context from the incoming request. That context is then used to create the new span.

```golang
func StartSpanFromRequest(tracer opentracing.Tracer, r *http.Request, operationName string) opentracing.Span {
    parentSpanContext, _ := tracer.Extract(opentracing.HTTPHeaders, opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(r.Header))
    span := tracer.StartSpan(operationName, ext.RPCServerOption(parentSpanContext))
    return span
}
```

When making HTTP requests to other services, inject the current span context into the HTTP headers. That allows the called service to extract the parent span context and create a child span.

Example of creating a child span, when making an HTTP request to another service:

```golang
span := StartSpanFromRequest(tracer, r, "customer method")
defer span.Finish()

// Inject current span context into the headers of the outgoing request
outgoingRequest, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://other-service-url", nil)
Inject(span, outgoingRequest)

// Make the request
//
```

Example of using the span in the called service:

```golang
// In the called service
func SomeHTTPHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    span := StartSpanFromRequest(tracer, r, "called method")
    defer span.Finish()

    // Business logic
    // 
}
```

You need to propagate the span context for all inter-service calls to maintain the trace continuity.